# Conditional regex capture, from grepping array of hashes

Tags: regex, perl, if-statement

Given the following anonymous array of hashes:

```
$fields_dump = [
    {
        'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL' => 'telco_hier_building',
        'APPROVER_ORDER' => '0',
        'IS_READONLY' => '0',
        'FORM_ID' => '3913',
        'REFERENCE' => 'building',
    },
    {
        'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL' => 'Request Type',
        'APPROVER_ORDER' => '0',
        'IS_READONLY' => '0',
        'FORM_ID' => '3913',
        'REFERENCE' => 'request_type',

    },
    {
        'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL' => 'Request Completion Date',
        'APPROVER_ORDER' => '0',
        'IS_READONLY' => '0',
        'FORM_ID' => '3913',
        'REFERENCE' => 'request_completion_date',
    },
```

I want to conditionally grep the array by `DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL` for the value of either `telco_hier_building` or `telco_imac_building`. When it succeeds I need to extract up to the second underscore of the value that was matched.

I am using the following code:

```
if  ( grep { $_->{DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL} =~ m/(telco_hier_|telco_imac_)building/ } @$fields_dump ) {
    my $telco_prefix = $1;
    ...
}
```

The conditional triggers properly, but regex `$1` assignment is blank, when in this example case, it should be `telco_hier_`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The match is scoped to the [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) `{}` code block.  You can use a `for` loop instead:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $fields_dump = [
    {
        'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL' => 'telco_hier_building',
        'APPROVER_ORDER' => '0',
        'IS_READONLY' => '0',
        'FORM_ID' => '3913',
        'REFERENCE' => 'building',
    },
    {
        'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL' => 'Request Type',
        'APPROVER_ORDER' => '0',
        'IS_READONLY' => '0',
        'FORM_ID' => '3913',
        'REFERENCE' => 'request_type',

    },
    {
        'DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL' => 'Request Completion Date',
        'APPROVER_ORDER' => '0',
        'IS_READONLY' => '0',
        'FORM_ID' => '3913',
        'REFERENCE' => 'request_completion_date',
    },
];

for (@{ $fields_dump }) {
    if ($_->{DEFAULT_FIELD_LABEL} =~ m/(telco_hier_|telco_imac_)building/) {
        my $telco_prefix = $1;
        print "$telco_prefix\n";
    }
}
```

**Output** is:

```
telco_hier_
```

Further explanation in [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions).